# CSS positioning in JQuery mobile with own stylesheet

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, jquery-mobile

I have written a small app in JQuery mobile and the app works as expected if I use the iOS emulator in Chrome.

If I run the app on an iPad Mini, there appears to be a problem regarding the css styles (the JQuery functionality works fine).

Specifically, some elements that a not in the standard JQuery stylesheet are not displayed.

For illustration, I have attached two screenshots of the same page, once in the emulator and once on an iPad. Here the user touches the blue circle and the text changes (this interaction works in both the emulator and the iPad).

I've read a couple of [similar](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/use-custom-css-with-jquerymobile) questions but I could not figure out how to get it working. It is essential that I use custom elements like circled touch areas and position them accurately. Giving the element the `data-role=none` attribute did not fix this.

Since it was suggested that the loading of stylesheets could be problematic, this is my `<head>` with the stylesheets and the jquery-mobile cdns.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./theme/mobilecittheme.min.css" media="screen and (orientation: landscape)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./theme/structure.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./MYSTYLESHEET.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

The blue circled element is:

```
<div id="target" data-role="none">Tap here to generate the control item</div>
```

and the css for the element shown on the screenshots is this:

```
#target {
  border: blue 2px solid;
  width: 25%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

It seems as if it is especially the positioning of the element (it should be centered as in the emulator example).

How can I fix this?

[image: iOS emulator][image: iOS on iPad Mini]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps others that have similar problems:

I've found a solution to this now after experimenting a bit with the stylesheet:

The problem seems to lie in the positioning of the element with in turn is problematic due to the responsive centering:

Apparently the responsive centering in the CSS like this

```
margin: 0;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

does not work in JQuery Mobile (any ideas why that is?)

I have worked around it and written a JQuery function that does the centering programmatically:

```
function css_center(object) {
  object.css({
  "margin-left": -($(object).width() / 2),
  "margin-top": -($(object).height() / 2)
 });
}
```

*(note that `margin-top` needs to be `-($(object).width() / 2` if the object is a responsively created square)*

This function needs to be called once the page is loaded:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#pageID', function() {
  css_center_square($("#target"));
});
```

However, this does not work either since the function is not called at the start. I have addressed this an interval:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#pageID', function() {
  setInterval(function(){
    css_center_square($("#target"));
  }, 25);
});
```

This runs the function every 25ms and it works as I want it to. I've tested it on the iPad Mini and it worked as expected.

There are definitely nicer solutions, but this one does the trick and works for me. If there are better solutions or explanations to the problem itself, I still want to know..